# set server time as default at the calendar

Tags: joomla-3.x, configuration, date, calendar

I am new to Joomla.
I have a question. I'll clarify my question:

In the calendar that was we make from the calendar field. [This link](https://docs.joomla.org/Calendar_form_field_type) is calendar field doc.
when a user comes to the site this calendar uses his time no server time. for example, now we are on 31, March. if the user changes his time to 11, March; when this user clicks on Today the field had sets Today as 11 March, not 31 March. I want this calendar to use our server time and the time zone we set in config. say to me if it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

why would someone has a totaly wrong date on his system?!
but to answer your question: have you tried to set the filter to server_utc?

from the docs:
filter (optional) is time zone to be used. There are two values; server_utc and user_utc. The first one is server time zone and the later is user time zone as configured in global configuration and user information respectively.

to be honest i have not yet tested what happens when you then click on the today button and you have a wrong date setted up in your system. but even then - set the filter is the only option where you could config that with the default date / datetime field.

so if its set then to the servers today value - it is correct
if it sets it to the (wrong) users date its also correct behavior (there is nothing written in the docs to which setting the today button refers to...